# How to add item/entity to a queue dynamics crm 2011 using SOAP endpoint

Tags: queue, entity, dynamics-crm-2011

How can I add an item/entity to a queue in dynamics crm 2011 programmatically using SOAP calls. Any help will greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [AddToQueueRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.addtoqueuerequest.aspx) and CRM organization service endpoint to add item to the queue.
For more details see [this post](http://worldofdynamics.blogspot.com/2012/05/dynamics-crm-2011-addtoqueuerequest-via.html). Or [this one](http://mileyja.blogspot.com/2011/12/add-activity-to-queue-in-microsoft.html)

Try more Googling before asking the question. It's not very hard to find this info.

Comment: Thank you @andriikulyk. I am new to dynamics crm, therefore I asked. I scour the web more next time before asking.

Comment: and worst thing in SO is #link-only-answers !
please oh please do not do this

Comment: @MuhammadNaderi Election week started, amount of sarcastic and non constructive comments about posts tripled.
Updated the answer, hope that you will sleep better after this.